# Why Jade sometimes shows head content?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I have a nodeJS web app using Jade. Sometimes(*) when loading it I get some head content (content configured in the head part of the Jade template) that should not be shown (I expect to see just the body content).

Below is the Jade configuration used:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    base(href=config.suffixHostPath)
    title= title
    meta(name="google-site-verification" content="xMnXgGQJouIg4Og9hQUMHwXwaVlMQ0dFxDv4g_N3iOo")
    script(type='text/javascript').
      // If no https and https is required or no suffixHostPath and suffixHostPath is defined and
      // if not in Studio, redirect the user.
      var suffixRegExp = new RegExp('!{config.suffixHostPath}(\/+|$)');
      if (((window.location.protocol === 'http:' && '!{config.supportHttps}' === 'true') ||
          ('!{config.suffixHostPath}' && !suffixRegExp.test(window.location.href))) &&
          '!{config.client}' !== 'studio') {
        window.location.href = '!{config.hostname}' + '!{config.suffixHostPath}' + (window.location.hash ? window.location.hash : '#!/');
      }

    link(rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=stylesUrl)
    each url in dependencies
      script(src=url)

    script(type='text/javascript').
      (function(angular) {
        angular.module('app')
          .constant('myConfig',
            !{JSON.stringify(config)}
          );
      })(window.angular);
      // After all scripts loaded, override repo_host if in Studio.
      if ('!{config.client}' === 'studio') {
        window.repo_host = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host;
      }

  body
    #my-app(ng-app='app')
      div(ui-view)
```

This un-appropriate starts with a map of properties (the ones configured in the app) and then it continues with part of the script placed in the Jade configuration:

```
});})(window.angular); // After all scripts loaded, override repo_host if in Studio. if (" === 'studio') { window.repo_host = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host; }
```

(*) it shows up just some times (in some "random" way).

Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you show what type of markup is produced when the head content is "shown"?

Comment: I've just update the question with that info. Thanks for the welcome!